# How to export Icedove Enigmail public key fully in Debian?

Tags: debian, key-authentication, enigmail, icedove

I want to share the key at my homepage. I cannot find any setting in Icedove for the task. There is *View settings for this account* but it does not contain any tool for exporting the public key. I can find the short ID but I want it fully.

You can install enigmail by : `sudo apt-get install enigmail`.

OS: Debian 8.7
Icedove:  Icedove 45.6.0

Comment: Is the Enigmail plugin actually installed in Icedove aka Thunderbird ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have not connected the key to gpg-ring"?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, I think. You can install it by the last command in the bobdy.

Comment: @StephenKitt I removed the part because it is not relevant here. - - It was about the key ring about which there is a part in enigmail settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [Enigmail wiki](https://enigmail.wiki/Key_Management), you can export your public key as follows:

- open the key management window (in the Icedove menu, Enigmail / Key Management)
- select your key
- open the file export dialog (in the key management window's menu, File / Export Keys to File)
- click on Export Public Keys Only

If the Icedove menu isn't visible, there are two ways to access it: you can either use the hamburger icon just to the right of the search box (it says “Display the Icedove Menu” when you hover over it), or right-click in the tab bar at the top of the window and select “Menu Bar”.

Comment: I'm not sure *what* you're trying to do. In my main Icedove menu, I have an Enigmail menu, and I access the key management window using the Key Management entry in that menu.

Comment: I tested this with Icedove 45.6.0 and Enigmail 1.8.2, using the Debian 8 packages (on a Debian 8 system).

Comment: How do you open the key management window of Enigmail?

Comment: I open it using the Icedove menu. In the Icedove menu, I have File, Edit, View, Go, Message, Events and Tasks, Enigmail, Tools and Help; in the Enigmail menu, the Key Management entry (the second entry in the menu) opens the key management window.